Google Account Service stoped working and starting throwing invalid JWT after a while
This post is hidden. It was deleted 8 mins ago by M--.
Hey everyone i hope everyone is doing great. am a freelancer and am currently working on an application for a client where some parts of the system uses google sheets to read and write so as any other dev would do am using google client service to make the api connection between the server and google sheets but i ran into some issues. i have noticed that after a while of using the google service account it started giving me invalid JWT Signature until i generate a new service account so am just wondering now is this a common issue ? is it a quota issue ? how do people get around this problem ? or are they just generating new service accounts every time this happens? because at this moment am not even sure whats actually happening to it. so if anyone can shine a little light on it that would be amazing.
this is the response am getting when i try to generate a token or try to connect to the server.
data: {
  error: 'invalid_grant',
  error_description: 'Invalid JWT Signature.'
}

if you need more light on the issue i would be happy to discus it...
I tried to look for a paid solution but google service doesn't offer a paid version of it.
